# Redirect each user to specific pages based on their role

Tags: redirect, user-roles

I want to make a multi-user website. Different types of users are Students, Teachers, Parents, Admin and counselor. I want to redirect each user to specific pages based on their type after logging in. How do I proceed? Is any plugin available?

How do I carry out registration and login?

Say, students should be redirected to a page `student.php` if and only if he is a student.
Teachers should be redirected to say `teacher.php`.

All types of users have different dashboards.

Comment: You can save their roles in meta fields and on login you can check the field and add the redirection accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You would make use of the [login_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter.

The example in the documentation looks a lot like what you are asking:

```
/**
 * Redirect user after successful login.
 *
 * @param string $redirect_to URL to redirect to.
 * @param string $request URL the user is coming from.
 * @param object $user Logged user's data.
 * @return string
 */

function wpse306427_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    //is there a user to check?
    if (isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {
        //check for subscribers
        if (in_array('subscriber', $user->roles)) {
            // redirect them to another URL, in this case, the homepage 
            $redirect_to =  home_url();
        }
    }

    return $redirect_to;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse306427_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

You would put this code in a plug-in or in your theme's function.php.

Comment: This is only good for the moment of login... users can still log in and the enter a different url

Comment: @SagiveSEO That's correct, this code does not enforce URL restrictions. There are other great answers for that on this stack exchange if you need this.